# Automation testing in separate repo github

Tags: github-actions, playwright, playwright-test

I am trying to set it up so every time I set up a PR in a GitHub repo it runs the playwright automation tests in a separate repo.

Application Repo file:

```
name: View Test Results
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize]

jobs:
  view-test-results:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          repository: benparr64/kegthat-automation-tests
          name: playwright-report
      - run: ls playwright-report/
```

And automation test file:

```
name: Playwright Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, master ]
jobs:
  test:
    timeout-minutes: 60
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 16
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - name: Install Playwright Browsers
      run: npx playwright install --with-deps
    - name: Run Playwright tests
      run: npx playwright test
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      if: always()
      with:
        name: playwright-report
        path: playwright-report/
        retention-days: 30
```

This is not working at all have tried lots of different ways of doing this. One repo is called kegthat-automation-tests and the other is called kegthat-headless. I think I just need to find a way of accessing the artifact from other repo but cant figure this out...

The GitHub action for playwright tests is passing okay.

It is a problem with view test results. Current error is

```
Unexpected input(s) 'repository', valid inputs are ['name', 'path']
```

Comment: does your code manage to run the second repo?

Comment: Yes automation test project works great

Comment: yes but I mean, is it triggered from your code? what is actually not working?

Comment: the automation tests are triggered, but the action in website code is not able to find the test results